# JS HTML Time value.getHours() is showing NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JS and as part of this I was trying to build a HTML page where based on date and time input of EST, I will get IST date and hour in the label. However, I am struggling to get hours and minutes out from HTML input so that I can set these hours into selected. If any of you experts can help me out here, will be really appreciated.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function calcTime() {
            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            var selectedDate = document.getElementById('date').value;
            var selectedTime = document.getElementById('time');
            selectedDate.setHours(selectedTime.getHours());
            selectedDate.setMinutes(selectedTime.getMinutes());
            var traceHours = new Time(selectedTime);
            var markHours = traceHours.getHours();
            nd = new Date(selectedTime + (3600000 * 9.5));
            output.innerHTML = updatedDate;
        }
    </script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    Select a date:
    <input id=date type="date">
    <input id=time type="time">
    </br>
    <button id=submit onclick="calcTime();return false;">Click to check Time</button>
    Time to EST is:
    <B>
        <blink>
            <DIV style="background-color: rgb(25, 236, 208)" id=result></DIV>
        </blink>
    </B>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What is it that you are attempting to do with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the `.value` of the `input` elements, **which are text**, [create a new `Date` from their values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and then you can call a `Date` method on that.

You also have several other HTML and JavaScript problems, for example, there is no such thing as a `Time` object in JavaScript, so this will fail:

```
var traceHours = new Time(selectedTime);
```

Frankly, it's clear that you've gotten this code straight out of 1995 (seriously). There are a lot of things that are no longer correct (i.e. `blink` has been deprecated for many years [thank God!]).

See the HTML and JavaScript comments below for details.

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
      <style>
         /* Don't do styling in HTML, separate it into CSS */
         #result { font-weight:bold; background-color: rgb(25, 236, 208); }
      </style>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    Select a date: 
    <input id=date type="date">
    <input id=time type="time"><br> <!-- There's no such thing as </br> -->
    <button id="submit">Click to check Time</button>

    <!-- Don't use inline event attributes like onClick. Do that work in JavaScript.
         Also, don't use an HTML tag because of the formatting the browser applies to
         it, like <b>. Styling is done with CSS, not HTML. -->
    Time to EST is: <DIV id="result"></DIV>

    <!-- Place your <script> element just before the closing BODY tag
         so that by the time the parser gets here, all the HTML will have
         been read into memory. Also, type=javascript isn't necessary since
         that is the default type. -->
    <script> 
       // Get your DOM references just once, not every time the function runs
       var output = document.getElementById("result");
       var dateElement = document.getElementById('date')
       var timeElement = document.getElementById('time');
       
       // Set up events in JavaScript, not with inline HTML event attributes
       document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", calcTime);

       function calcTime() {
         // Create a new Date object from the two HTML inputs
         var est = new Date(dateElement.value + " " + timeElement.value);         
         
         // Write out the results. Don't use .innerHTML when there is no HTML.
         // Use .textContent instead and just call .toISOString() to get UTC time.
         result.textContent = 'USA time: '+ est.toISOString();
       }     
   </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thank you @Scott. I have learned a lot from your reply. I will update my code based on your recommendation. Based on jcjcjc's reply. I have updated my code and here is how it looks like now:

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer. Thanks again for your help. I was able to change the code you have provided and made changes which is now functioning well. Thanks again for your support.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things going on here:

1. You need to call `value` after `document.getElementById('time')`, otherwise you're working with the element
2. Both `selectedDate` and `selectedTime` are just string values, so you won't be able to call DateTime methods like `getHours` on either of them
3. To address the above, simply create a new instance of `Date` using `selectedDate` and `selectedTime` like this: `var date = new Date(selectedDate + ': ' + selectedTime);` This works because the `Date` constructor can accept any parseable date string ([cf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), this should be ok for your purposes, but be aware that this won't work on all browsers, so be careful)
4. You can now display the stringified date on your page

Full code example:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('result');
var selectedDate = document.getElementById('date').value;
var selectedTime = document.getElementById('time').value;
var date = new Date(selectedDate + ': ' + selectedTime);

output.innerHTML = date;
```

A couple extra things, you'll probably want to add quotes around your `id=` tags in the HTML; the `</br>` should be `<br />` or just `<b>`; probably want to stick with lowercase for all your HTML tags; the `<blink>` tag is considered obsolete and has been deprecated, so you shouldn't use it; setting `innerHTML` on an element will completely replace the child nodes, so your string "Time to EST is:" will be entirely replaced by the string value for your date object.

Hope this all helps.

Comment: Thank you so much jcjcjc. I appreciate you taking the time to answer. Your answer partially solves my problem. What I was looking for is get value of the date and time inputs and then add variable values ex. 9 hours and 30 minutes as the output. Nonetheless, thanks for the date time input solution, let me give your code a try.

Comment: JavaScript's Date API is pretty poor, so there isn't a clean way to add hours, seconds, etc.

Given a Date object, though, you can do something like: 


`function addHoursToDate(dateObj, numHours) {
  return dateObj.setTime(dateObj.getTime() + (numHours * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}`

`getTime` returns ms, hence the * 60 * 60 * 1000

With a little tweaking, you could do the same to add days, minutes and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to learn similar things to be done in different ways. If you have any advice or learning links, please share. I am trying to grab JS now. I came across moment.js but that's a whole learning by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Look at answer from @jcjcjcjc.
Furthermore if you really want to access hours and minutes or set the time you can do

```
var selectedTime = document.getElementById('time').value;
hours = selectedTime.split(":")[0];
minutes = selectedTime.split(":")[1];
document.getElementById('time').value = "13:45:00.000";
```

Comment: That is not the way to get hours and minutes. You've done a complete end run around the entire point of the `Date` API.

Answer (score 0):

you can use getHours() on object Date only

```
function calcTime() {
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value,
    time = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var dateTime = date +" " + time;
    nd = new Date(dateTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer partially solves my problem. What I was looking for is get value of the date and time then add 9 hours and 30 minutes as the output. Let me give your code a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great community, I really appreciate all of you taking time to resolve my problem. Scott Marcus, jcjcjc, 45ccccw32, Leung King Tim and everyone. I was able to resolve my issue by the code provided by Scott. Please find below the final code for anyone looking for this in future.

```js
       var output = document.getElementById("result");
       var dateElement = document.getElementById('date')
       var timeElement = document.getElementById('time');   

       document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", calcTime);

       function calcTime() {
         // Create a new Date object from the two HTML inputs
         var est = new Date(dateElement.value + " " + (timeElement.value));         
         if(est.getMinutes>=30){
            est.setMinutes(est.getMinutes() + 30);
            est.setHours(est.getHours + 1);
         }
         else{
             est.setMinutes(est.getMinutes() + 30);
         }
         if(est.getHours>=24){
            est.setHours(est.getHours() + 9);
            est.setDate(est.getDate() + 1);
         }
         else{
             est.setHours(est.getHours() + 9);
         }
         
         result.textContent = 'India time: '+ est.toLocaleString();
       }
```

```css
         #result { font-weight:bold; background-color: rgb(25, 236, 208); }
```

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>

    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    Select a date: 
    <input id=date type="date">
    <input id=time type="time"><br> 
    <button id="submit">Click to check Time</button>

    Time to EST is: <DIV id="result"></DIV>
    
</BODY>
</HTML>
```